# Linq add list inside a list in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am working on adding a child model list inside a parent model list using linq.
I got the parent and child model as the structure below.

```
public string A { get; set; }
public string B { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<ListItem> Childrens { get; set; }
```

I am manage to get some data for my parent model.

```
var Parent = 
    (from c in ExpenseCategorylist
     select new ListItem
     {
         A = c.Key,
         B = c.Value,
         Childrens = new List<ListItem>()
     }).ToList();
```

Now I am going to add data to the child model.

```
foreach(var c in Parent)
{
    var child= 
        (from d in ExpenseTypeList
        select new ListItem
        {
            A = d.Key,
            B = d.Value,
            Childrens = null,
        }).ToList();

c.Childrens.ToList().AddRange(child);
}
```

I am not able to update my parent model. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: `ToList()` creates new instance of collection, maybe this `c.Childrens = c.Childrens.Concat(data).ToList()` ?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: What is data and what do you do with child? What are ExpenseCategorylist and ExpenseTypeList?

Comment: Why do we have an `IEnumerable` here?  `IEnumerable `  Contains only  `GetEnumerator` method to get  `Enumerator ` and make a looping. While 
 `ICollection ` is containing the following methods :  `Add `/ `Remove `/ `Contains `/ `Count `/ `CopyTo `.
 `ICollection ` is inherited from  `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Alexey still not able to insert

Comment: @OlivierRogier It is a result in List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> which i get it from the other function

Comment: Data is not define. The first code block as property name thats doesn't match the rest of the code and no class name. I guess I get the idea, but I don't know if every mistake is only in the question and not in the real code. Or exist in the real code and need to be fix. We are not nitpicking, we just lack a basic [mre]. My bet is still on  Alexey comment. and the Wrong data structure

Comment: child is never used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Alexey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5418754/alexey) commented

```
c.Childrens.ToList().AddRange(child);
```

Will not add element to `c.Childrens`, but to a List created on the fly by `.ToList()`.

In order to do that you can either do :

```
testA.innerList= testA.innerList.Concat(data).ToList();

((List<int>)testA.innerList).AddRange(data);
```

With this simplify model for example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var data = new []{1,2,3,4,5,6};

     var testA = 
         new TestA {
            Label="aa",
            innerList= new List<int>()
         };

    ///Err: IEnumerable doesn't contains AddRange
    //testA.innerList.AddRange(data);


    //as  Alexey commented
    testA.innerList= testA.innerList.Concat(data).ToList();
    testA.innerList.Dump();// Test:  Works
    testA.innerList=new List<int>(); //reset

    //Cast      
    ((List<int>)testA.innerList).AddRange(data);        
    testA.innerList.Dump();// Test:  Works  

    // With extention method
    testA.innerList.AddRange(data); 
    testA.innerList.Dump();// Test:  Works  
    testA.innerList=new List<int>(); //reset

}

public class TestA{
    public string Label {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<int> innerList {get; set;}   
}
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8cmECh)

If AddRange on IEnumerable / ICollection / IList, you may consider writing an Extention method on IEnumerable.

```
public static void AddRange<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items)
{
  ((List<T>)collection).AddRange(items);    
}
```

Comment: @ChoyWingLun, added extention method code and demo.